# Setter for 'isMenuVisible' was deprecated in iOS 13.0

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, ios13, uimenucontroller

In iOS 13.0, Setter for 'isMenuVisible' was deprecated, What is alternate of isMenuVisible in iOS 13 (Swift 5+)?

```
UIMenuController.shared.isMenuVisible = false
```

Answer (score 7):

Use showMenuFromView:rect: or hideMenuFromView: instead.

```
UIMenuController.shared.hideMenu()
```

Apple documentation links -

- For hiding menu

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uimenucontroller/3044215-hidemenu
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uimenucontroller/3044216-hidemenu

- For showing menu

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uimenucontroller/3044217-showmenu